# can not access HBase status UI on http://localhost:60010

Tags: hbase

I use ubuntu 12.04, after download and un-tar hbase-0.94.1.jar. I started hbash in standalone mode by the following command

```
user@ubuntu:~/temp/hbase-0.94.1$ bin/start-hbase.sh 
starting master, logging to /home/user/temp/hbase-0.94.1/bin/../logs/hbase-user-master-ubuntu.out
```

but when I try to access hbash status UI on

```
http://localhost:60010
```

, I got "Unable to connect".

Thanks.

Dan

Answer (score 51):

After the 0.98 version port numbers have changed. It is now 16010 instead of 60010). Check this page for general UI troubleshooting: http://hbase.apache.org/book/trouble.tools.html

Comment: This. "The Master starts a web-interface on port 16010 by default. (Up to and including 0.98 this was port 60010)". Even googling "hbase ports" says 60010, but I was on 1.0.1 confused for the longest time

Answer (score 2):

First check log files to see if HBase started correctly. Then try with IP address

Answer (score 2):

First check "**hbase-hduser-master-ubuntu.log**" file from **logs** folder of your hbase installed path

**if you are getting following error**

2014-09-07 20:22:24,505 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: **HMaster Aborted**
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2794)

compare **core-site.xml** of ***Hadoop*** with **hbase-site.xml** of ***hbase***. hdfs URL should be same in both file

***core-site.xml***

```
 <configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://192.168.203.130:9000</value>
    </property>
 </configuration>
```

***hbase-site.xml***

```
 <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <!-- <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value> -->
    <value>hdfs://192.168.203.130:9000/hbase</value> 
    <description>The directory shared by RegionServers.
    </description>
 </property>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try accessing HBase master web-ui with http://localhost:16010